# I am new to ruby language , and trying to create a text adventure game , i want to include two strings

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I want the user to type anything, but it should include two strings like "look" and "right", if both are included in the sentence then the program will go to the next line. 
I am new to ruby, just getting myself familiar with the language.

I have tried `&&` and `||` but it doesnt work

```
puts " in which direction do you want to look"  
input = gets.chomp.to_s 

if input.include? == "look" && "right"  
    puts " There is a dead end on the right"  
  elsif input.include? "look" && "left"  
     puts "there is a narrow way , going towards the woods"  
  else   

    puts "i dont understand what you are trying to say"  

 end
```

Comment: That's not how `include?` works, at all. Here's docs: [String#include?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.0.preview2/String.html#method-i-include-3F). Here's what you needed to write: `input.include?("look") && input.include?("right")`

Comment: Thanks man , really appreciate your help , will try it and let you know if its working .

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: yeah sure , will do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `input.include? "look" && "right"`, you need to compare the statements one by one.

```
if input.include?("look") && input.include?("right")
    puts " There is a dead end on the right"  
  elsif input.include?("look") && input.include?("left")
     puts "there is a narrow way , going towards the woods"  
  else   
    puts "i dont understand what you are trying to say"  
 end
```

Logically, `input.include? "look"` would either return true or false, and `input.include? "right"` would also return true or false. Both statements need to be true in order for it to work!

Comment: thanks for helping , really helped me to understand .. it works fine now .

Comment: Glad to help!! :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to define a method which handles the input and returns the `direction` to be use in the `if/then/else`:

```
def get_direction(input)
  keywords = ['look', 'left', 'right']
  directions = {101 => :right, 110 => :left}
  directions.default = :none
  input = input.scan(/\w+/).map(&:downcase).uniq
  key = keywords.map { |k| input.include? k }.map{ |e| e ? 1 : 0 }.join().to_i
  directions[key]
end
```

---

These are few examples of method calls:

```
get_direction("Yes. Look at your right now! Right now! Look!") #=> :right
get_direction("Yes. Look at your left now!") #=> :left
get_direction("Look right. Left them there!") #=> :none
get_direction("Stay right here!") #=> :none
```

---

Inside the method you can find a [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/String.html#method-i-scan) for splitting the input into words. Also, there is a `.map(&:downcase)` to assure case insensitivity, using [Array#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Array.html#method-i-map). It uses a [Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Hash.html) to select the output.

Add `p` to print out this line to understand how it is working:

```
p key = keywords.map { |k| input.include? k }.map{ |e| e ? 1 : 0 }.join().to_i
```

---

Now you can use the method this way:

```
direction = get_direction(gets.chomp.to_s)

if  direction == :right
  p 'right'
elsif direction == :left
  p 'left'
else
  p 'none'
end
```

Comment: oh yeah thanks , i will sure check this set class , looks great. thanks